# Oracle and TimesTen - Can you bind it?

Tags: oracle

I have some questions, that I like to know to my MSc research.

Lets consider following situation:
I have two small tables A and B.
And two big tables C and D.
I want to put A and B in TimesTen and C and D (because they are to big) in standard Oracle database.
Can I configure system that way, that queries to A and B will be RAM-only queries and queries for C and D will be standard database queries?
I want this to work transparent to user: user makes query and don't know, if he is querying TimesTen or standard Oracle.
If above is possible: What about queries in which user joins A and C? Will A be read from memory or from disk?

I don't need to know how to do it. Only if its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you use pass through. The client connects to the TT instance and TT passes the query through to the Oracle rdbms, when needed. Why not just add a few more nodes to the grid and also cache the bigger tables?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I only need information for "state of art" part of my work. So it is possible to configure that way, that wile join is invoked some data will be taken from TimesTen and some from standard Oracle?

Comment: It is not explicitly mentioned but when reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21634/operations.htm#TTCAC291 a conclusion can be that in your case the complete SQL runs in the rdbms because tables are missing in TT.